# how to insert values from a access database to a combobox in visual basic 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have managed to insert only 1 value, the first value I insert in the database.
The problem is, that I have more than 1 value in the combobox, but it only inserts the first one.

This is the code I have:

```
Dim query1 As New OleDbCommand(" SELECT MembrosCompasso.BI, MembrosCompasso.Ano FROM Compasso INNER JOIN MembrosCompasso ON Compasso.idCompasso = MembrosCompasso.idCompasso WHERE BI=@BI ", con)
        query1.Parameters.Add("@BI", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = BI.Text
        Dim dr1 As OleDbDataReader = query1.ExecuteReader

        Try
            If dr1.HasRows Then
                dr1.Read()
                Ano.Items.Item.add(dr1("Ano"))
            Else
                MsgBox("Não exsitem registos!")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' tratamento de erros
        Finally
            dr.Close()
            con.Close()
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using a DataReader, the current position advances by one row every time you call the `.Read` method, you don't get all the records in the reader with one call. `Read` returns a boolean that tells you whether it succeeded or not so that you know whether you can advance to the next record, so your code should look more like:

```
...
If dr1.HasRows Then
    'Loop around the reader until we run out of rows
    While dr1.Read
        'Add each rows' item to the combobox
        Ano.Items.Item.add(dr1("Ano"))
    End While
Else
...
```

Comment: @P.Campos No problem. You should mark it as the accepted answer, by clicking the tick on the left.